# Hex editor, space between bytes

Tags: java, swing, hex

I'm trying to create a hex editor and ran into a problem.
I made a JTextarea to display the contents of a .dat file with after every byte a space. Ofcourse when you start to edit it you can remove the space and put everything after each other etc. One of my great examples is HxD, I want to create something like that. I also looked into DocumentFilter, but I don't think that will help me.
Now my question is, how can I make some sort of columns in which the bytes are being displayed?

Comment: "Best" depends on preferences which are opinion-based making it off-topic for this site. Try to change your question into something more *specific* like: how to let JTextArea accept only specified characters like 0 and 1?

Comment: I updated my question, I hope it is more specific like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the data to display in columns by adding a tab character after every byte that has been converted to a two character string:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
textArea.setFont( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 16) );
textArea.setTabSize(3);
textArea.setText("a1\ta2\ta3\ta4\ta5\ni1\ti2\ti3\ti4\ti5\nW1\tW2\tW3\tW4\tW5\n");
```